# Can I express this set as a sum of sets?

Tags: analysis

Let $X, Y_{1}, ..., Y_{p}$ be nonempty subsets of $R^n, n \geq 1$. Can I express the set
$$
\left\{x + \sum_{j = 1}^{p}v_j \mid x \in X, v_j \in Y_j, (v_1)_{n} = \dots = (v_p)_{n}\right\}
$$
as a sum of sets, i.e $A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$?

Comment: I think you're missing $X$ in the definition. And some triviality clause, otherwise $B=\{{\vec 0}\}$ would do the trick.

Comment: $v_{1_n}$? I don't know what you meant be that.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC It's the n-th coordinate of the vector $v_1$

Comment: Ah, $(v_1)_n$, not $v_{\{1_n\}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I've rectified the definition. As for trivialities, I require A = X and B to be itself a sum of sets involving the $Y_j$'s.